# receiving batch error running an update on talend into PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, talend

I have a talend solution where inside it rests a `tMap --> tPostgreSQLOutput`.

Inside the schema is a `integer`(key field) and a Date(Timestamp) in the format of `"dd-MM-yyyy  HH:mm:ss"`.  The intent is to update the date field with the current time/date (Timestamp).

the date is set with this talend function call in the tMap:

```
TalendDate.parseDate("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", TalendDate.getDate("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
```

I have confirmed the date(timestamp) format, and confirmed that the timestamp data type in the PostgreSQL database.  However, I'm getting this error upon runtime:

```
Batch entry 0 UPDATE "bitcoin_options" SET "last_notified" = 2017-04-08 12:02:40.000000 -05:00:00 WHERE "id" = 3 was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.
```

I took the query it errored and manually ran it into PostgreSQL.  I got this response:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "11"
LINE 1: ...bitcoin_options" SET "last_notified" = 2017-04-08 11:53:11.0...
                                                             ^
```

Again, I checked the format, the datatype, and compared them against other tables and their UPSERTS.  same format.  same datatype.

In addition, I attempted to add a second space between date and time, with no avail.

### UPDATE 1

I updated the `tMap` output to:

```
TalendDate.getCurrentDate();
```

and got the same error.
Thanks

### UPDATE 2

Here's my layout for Talend:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out.  after much trial and error.
The tPostgresSQLCommit x3 was redundant.  When I removed the first two and placed just one, it gave me the proper output.

LESSONS LEARNED:  You only need 1 commit.

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as the right answer. It may help others :)

Answer (score 2):

Notice your timestamp is not properly formatted:

`UPDATE "bitcoin_options" SET "last_notified" = '2017-04-08 12:02:40.000000 -05:00:00' WHERE "id" = 3`

It's missing the single quotes surrounding the timestamp. If you add those you should be good to go.

Comment: sorry....no dice.  still gives me an error: `Batch entry 0 UPDATE "bitcoin_options" SET "last_notified" = '2017-04-08 12:02:40.000000 -05:00:00' WHERE "id" = 3 was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.`